# Storing data in an array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am having a problem when storing data in a structure, what happens is that when I save a name, all the names are set to the last.

I have a whole day trying to find the error.

Here the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int id;
    char *nombre;
    int saldo;
} CLIENTES;

CLIENTES Cliente[5];
int n_client = 0;
void RegistrarCliente (char *nom, int saldo);
void Listar ();
int n_client;

void main (void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        char nombre[30];
        scanf ("%s", &nombre);
        RegistrarCliente (nombre, 250);
    }
    Listar ();
}

void RegistrarCliente (char *nom, int saldo)
{
    Cliente[n_client].id = n_client;
    Cliente[n_client].nombre = nom;
    Cliente[n_client].saldo = saldo;
    printf ("Cliente: %s registrado con una deuda de %d\n",
            Cliente[n_client].nombre, Cliente[n_client].saldo);
    n_client++;
}

void Listar ()
{
    printf ("%-10s%-13s%-10s\n", "ID", "NOMBRE", "SALDO");
    for (int i = 0; i < n_client; i++) {
        printf ("%-10d%-13s%-10d\n", Cliente[i].id, Cliente[i].nombre,
                Cliente[i].saldo);

    }
}
```

**Input/output**

```
Jhosh
    Cliente: Jhosh registrado con una deuda de 250
    Leo
    Cliente: Leo registrado con una deuda de 250
    Jhonny
    Cliente: Jhonny registrado con una deuda de 250
    Stweart
    Cliente: Stweart registrado con una deuda de 250
    Carlos
    Cliente: Carlos registrado con una deuda de 250
    ID        NOMBRE       SALDO
    0         Carlos       250
    1         Carlos       250
    2         Carlos       250
    3         Carlos       250
    4         Carlos       250
```

Comment: [`int main`](http://c-faq.com/ansi/voidmainbooks.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy the strings instead of assigning the pointer directly.

```
void RegistrarCliente(char * nom, int saldo)
{
    Cliente[n_client].nombre = malloc(strlen(nom) + 1); /* +1 for terminating null-character */
    if(Cliente[n_client].nombre == NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc");
        return;
    }
    Cliente[n_client].id = n_client;
    strcpy(Cliente[n_client].nombre, nom);
    Cliente[n_client].saldo = saldo;
    printf("Cliente: %s registrado con una deuda de %d\n", Cliente[n_client].nombre, Cliente[n_client].saldo);
    n_client++;
}
```

Please add `#include <stdlib.h>` in order to use `malloc()` and `#include <string.h>` in order to use `strlen()` and `strcpy()`.

As @R.Shrestha pointed out, you have to change `scanf("%s", &nombre);` to `scanf("%s", nombre);` because the former statement invokes *undefined behavior* for passing pointer to data having wrong type to `scanf()`: `%s` specifier calls for `char*`, but you passed `char (*)[30]`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this statement  scanf("%s", &nombre);  to  scanf("%s",nombre);//it is a input of string and '&' should not be used here and use strcpy() to copy string rather than to use assignment operator...Try this

Comment: Also `%29s` would prevent buffer overflow